# manually change marker position Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, location, marker

I've a mapActivity which shows me my position with a marker. now I want to correct the position manually. Is this possible? Do you know how I can do that? 
Thanks in advance!

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
            location.getLongitude());
    ReverseGeocodingTask rgt = new ReverseGeocodingTask();

    rgt.execute(userLocation);

}
```

Comment: there is a tutorial about on touch listener in [here](http://dimitar.me/how-to-detect-a-user-pantouchdrag-on-android-map-v2/). but you will provide your own logic when user can do it manually

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add markers yo your map with this:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-34.6033, -58.3817))
            .title("My position"));
```

So you can implement a custom marker for your position.

To add a marker when the user taps the map you can use [OnMapClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener.html)

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
         map.clear();
         map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(point)
            .snippet(""));

       }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but with this I need to set the location in the code. I would like to move the marker by clicking on the position on the map.

Comment: @user3379235 take a look now

Comment: Now I can add a marker. But I would like to change the poition of the marker I did already set(my location)

Comment: I've edited my previous answer, with [clear](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#clear%28%29) you can remove the previous marker. @user3379235